# Laravel 9 : How to upload photo take with mobile camera using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-9

In my project I need the users take photos with their phone and then send this photos to the server,

I already configure the input file field to open the camera, take the photo and show them in the form, but when  tried to save the file to the server, don't work, don't save the file, but properties like, name and extension passed to the controller.

When I tried to do the same on PC, upload photos stored in the PC, work perfectly.

This is my file input

```
<input type="file" name="imagen_upload" id="imagen_upload" capture="camera" accept="image/*"
              class="d-none">
```

This is my JS (jQuery)

```
      var formData;

      $(document).on('submit', '#form', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        formData = new FormData(this);
        return false;
      });

      $(document).on('click', '.btn-save', function(e) {
        $('#form').trigger('submit');
        var confirmation;
        foto = $('[name="imagen_upload"]').val();
        if (foto == null || foto == '') {
          toastr.error('Debe tomar una foto');
          return;
        }
        confirmation = confirm('¿Esta seguro que desea grabar esta foto?');
        if (confirmation) {
          $.post({
            url: '{{ route('subirFoto') }}',
            data: formData,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(data) {
              alert(data);
              if (data.status) {
                alert('Se grabo la foto correctamente');
              } else {
                alert('No se pudo grabar la foto, por favor intente de nuevo');
              }
            },
            error: function(data) {
              alert('Hubo un error');
            }
          })
        }
      })
```

This is the action at the controller

```
public function upload(Request $request)
    {
        $status = false;

        // Eliminar fotos previas
        $foto = Foto::whereInspeccionId($request->id)->whereTipo($request->tipo_foto)->first();
        if ($foto) {
            $foto->delete();
        }

        // Crear instacia de Foto
        $foto = new Foto();
        $foto->inspeccion_id = $request->id;
        if (Auth::user()) {
            $foto->autor = Auth::user()->id;
        } else {
            $foto->autor = $request->autor;
        }
        $foto->tipo = $request->tipo_foto;
        $img = $request->file('imagen_upload');
        $foto->asset = $img->getClientOriginalName();
        $save = $foto->save();


        // Cargar foto al servidor
        $dir = public_path() . '/../images/inspecciones/' . $foto->inspeccion_id . '/';
        $img->move($dir, $foto->asset);

        if ($save) {
            $status = true;
        }

        return response()->json(['status' => $status]);
    }
```

I need that  the photos taked with de mobile camera stored at the server just like when I select files at the PC